# Not enough permission from project owner to verify google in app subscriptions

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-developer-api

I am trying to verify google in app subscription on my server end.

It seems to me that I need to create a service account for that.

After linking google play to google cloud platform. I see that it automatically created a project "Google Play Android Developer" on my google cloud platform.

Now, i created a service account under the project "Google Play Android Developer" with "owner role" on the entire project.

But for some reason, when I use this service account and attempt to verify a purchaseToken, i get the error "The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation".

I am using a nodejs backend with this https://www.npmjs.com/package/iap library.

```
iap.verifyPayment('google', {
  receipt: "<purchaseToken>",
  keyObject: {
    "type": "service_account",
    "project_id": "<project_id_that_was_created_for_me>",
    "private_key_id": "<private_key_id>",
    "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nblah\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
    "client_email": "google-play-owner@project_id_that_was_created_for_me.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "client_id": "---",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_x509_cert_url": "---"
  },
  productId: "my.app.membership_1_month",
  subscription: true,
  packageName: "my.app"
}, function (error, response) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

This is the error I receive

```
"errors": [
   {
    "domain": "androidpublisher",
    "reason": "permissionDenied",
    "message": "The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation."
   }
  ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out, that I need to also grant access on the the google play console UI.

1. https://play.google.com/apps/publish

   - DO NOT CLICK INTO ANY OF YOUR APP
2. Go to settings on left
3. API Access on left
4. Service Accounts on RIGHT
5. Grant permission or create account there